# How to conceive a Turing machine that is the intersection of the languages of two Turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines

We have $ M = (Q,Σ,Γ,δ,q_0,q_a,q_r) $ and $ M′= (Q′, Σ , Γ′, δ′,q_0′,q_a′,q_r′)$.

We want to construct a standard Tm that recognize L(M) ∩ L(M′). How do I go about it? I don't have much more information than this. Anything to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: Its the same proof as for regular languages. Check that out first (under "closure properties of regular languages")

Answer (score 2):

What you ask might not be possible in general. If $L(T)$ denotes the set of words $x$ for which $T(x)$ accepts, and you do not have the additional assumption that $M$ and $M'$ recognize $L(M)$ and $L(M')$, respectively, then you could choose:

- $M$ as a Turing machine that takes another Turing machine $T$ as input and accepts if and only if $T$ halts on empty input. (Notice that such a Turing Machine $M$ exists).
- $M'$ as a Turing Machines that recognizes $\Sigma^*$.

Then, there is no Turing Machine $T$ that recognizes $L(M) \cap L(M') = L(M)$ since $T$ would solve the halting problem.

On the other hand, if you are fine with a Turing machine that accepts $L(M) \cap L(M')$ **or** if you have the additional assumption that $M$ and $M'$ recognize $L(M)$ and $L(M')$, respectively, your problem is solved by a Turing machine that, on input $x$, operates as follows:

- Simulate $M(x)$ until it halts (possibly never).
- If $M(x)$ rejects, reject.
- Simulate $M'(x)$ until it halts (possibly never).
- If $M'(x)$ rejects, reject.
- Accept.

Comment: @Evil, thank you! I fixed the symbol.